# Как сделать список с строки? Разделить строку, используя регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, list

Когда я делаю список из строки, как мне обозначить пределы того, что я хочу добавить к первому элементу, а что ко второму и так далее?

Например, у меня есть строка:

```
'I am a person (1995) Russia'
```

А моя цель создать такой список:

```
['I am man', '(1995)', 'Russia']
```

Comment: Как можно из `'I am a person'` получить `'I am man'` разделением строки? Вы читали свой вопрос прежде чем его опубликовать?

Comment: `как мне обозначить пределы того, что я хочу добавить к первому элементу, а что ко второму и так далее` — для начала нужно простым русским языком сформулировать правила, по которым вы будете разделять строку или выделять из неё элементы. Хорошая постановка задачи — половина решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601909/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5#comment816464_601912):

> Если перед (1995) стоит еще какое-то предложение в скобках, то можно
>   было бы как-то так сделать, чтобы программа делила на элементы списка
>   только до (1995) и после? (**вместо 1995 может стоять любое
>   четырехзначное число**)

Решение:

```
In [7]: s = 'I (0) am a (smart) person (1995) Russia'

In [8]: re.split(r'\s(\(\d{4}\))\s', s)
Out[8]: ['I (0) am a (smart) person', '(1995)', 'Russia']
```

[Описание и разбор данного регулярного выражения (на английском языке)](https://regex101.com/r/VECOst/1)

Comment: я очень извиняюсь но у меня возникла одна проблема. Если перед (1995)
стоит еще какое-то предложение в скобках, то можно было бы как-то так сделать, чтобы программа делила на элементы списка только до (1995) и после. (вместо 1995 может стоять любое четырехзначное число)

Comment: @Bernard, я исправил ответ

Comment: @MaxU это регулярное выражение применимо для специфических случаев, когда внутри скобок ровно четыре цифры. А ответ не объясняет, как выражение составлено, поэтому в таком виде он бесполезен (всем, включая автора вопроса, который сдаст домашнее задание, но ничему не научится).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я немного исправил ответ и добавил ссылку на пошаговое пояснение RegEx'a (на английском).